# Django-admin startproject mysite

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python and Django. I'm using Python 3.4.2 and Django 1.8
I'm stuck in the first set only:

```
C:\Users\admin>python                                     
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) tel)] on win32                                            
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
>>> import django                                         
>>> print (django.get_version())                          
1.8.3                                                     
>>> django-admin startproject mysite  
File "<stdin>", line 1 
 django-admin startproject mysite                                                  
^  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: you forgot the .py in admin

Comment: `C:\Users\admin>python  django-admin.py startproject mysite` should work.

Comment: Do not use django-admin inside a Python console. Use it on your terminal.

Comment: @EdwinLunando That is what I was thinking also. The SyntaxError doesn't come because of the missing file extension (.py). This command simply doesn't belong in the interpreter.

Comment: In windows there should be a file called `django-admin.exe` than does the same as `django-admin.py`. Windows will execute the exe file even if you don't enter the extension. `django-admin startproject mysite` should work from the shell exactly like `django-admin.py startproject mysite` if your PATH is set properly.

Answer (score 6):

You can't run the following command:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

within the Python interpreter.

It should be run on the command line. I don't have a lot of experience with Windows, but it should also work like with the Linux shell.

So run the above on the command line.

EDIT:

I would like to give some further explanation on this topic because it seems that some basics of Python syntax aren't really clear here.

When you start `python` either in Windows, MacOS X, GNU/Linux, BSD or whatever the Python shell or interpreter is started.
You can run your commands there and get an immediate output.

Running the above command produces SyntaxError. What causes this error? You already imported `django` as a module. In the first part (`django-admin`) you are extracting the value of `admin` which is not defined or imported anywhere from the value of `django` which is an imported module and not a variable. `django-admin` is for the interpreter a mathematical operation that can be performed on numbers (integers, floats). Putting `startproject` after that is for the Python interpreter calling another variable (same for `mysite`). Because the hypothetical calculation ends after `django-admin` adding another variable after that causes a SyntaxError.

This would also happen if you would try for example the following expression:

```
>>> 5 - 3 2
```

Using `django-admin.py startproject mysite` in the interpreter doesn't change much. It now looks for an attribute `py` of the object `admin` that hasn't been created.

On the other side if you run the command:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

on the command line, the file `django-admin.py` gets executed and parses the command line arguments `startproject` and `mysite`.

That said, running the command in the Python interpreter or on the command line are essentialy different things.

The answers saying you should just use the command, without explaining the meaning, are ignoring the error message and aren't really very useful.

I hope this helps for better comprehension of the problems you ran into.

Answer (score 5):

Did you add C:\Python27\Scripts to path?

Did you activate virtual-env?

and it should be `django-admin.py startproject` mysite with .py and should be run in command line.

Thats all I think can help. Good luck! :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is even more precise than my answer. Other answers are missing out to point the proper use of the command.

Answer (score 1):

you have opened python terminal just by typing python so i am assuming Python34.exe is already available in your environment path variables.

Now Also you have imported django successfully that means your source directory is also included in env variables.

Now you need to remember that you can not create a project from inside of python shell. So do a gracefull exit by typing exit() and then type `django-admin startproject mysite`

Let me know if it works...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems while trying to start a project. All I did was to open the command prompt as I am using windows and typed:

django-admin.py startproject mysite

I did this without typing python or whatsoever.. Once you have installed python and django properly, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

on windows cmd provide path to django-admin.py

exmaple:
c:\Django-2.2.6\django\bin\django-admin.py startproject myproject

Answer (score -1):

this should work...

django-admin.py startproject mysite