# How do I add Django to path

Tags: python, django, cmd

When I try and run the `django-admin` command it fails with the following error.

```sh
$ django-admin startproject pyshop

The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
 + django-admin startproject pyshop
```

What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379431/django-admin-startproject-mysite) should help.

Comment: did you install it in a python virtual environment? (venv or virtualenv). if so you may need to activate that environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download django first by `pip install django` or if you are using anaconda prompt than you can install that by `conda install django`